# how can i download file in remote admin tool?

Tags: vb.net, sockets

After I downloaded file, it is giving me smaller size then original file? 
if the File size **2014 k** I receive just **1024 k** and will lost connection

```
While True
   Dim numArray As Byte() = New Byte(1024) {}
   c.Poll(-1, SelectMode.SelectRead)

   Dim count As Long = c.Receive(numArray, 0, numArray.Length, SocketFlags.None)
   dw.FS.Write(numArray, 0, count)
   ind.long_1 += CLng(count)
   num3 += count

   Dim progressBar As ProgressBar = dw.ProgressBar1
   progressBar.Value = progressBar.Value + count
   dw.FS.Flush()

   Dim tr As Long = dw.SZ
   If num3 < tr Then
      Thread.Sleep(1)
   Else
      Exit While
   End If
End While
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please put more effort into explaining the problem as it's unclear what you are asking. Also please read: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: thank's the site not accept all the code I have an error   so  c is the socket  dw is the download form with button and progress bar fs is file stream

Comment: what you need more to explain